# Why "Namespace 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace' is not available to be referenced in this schema."?

Tags: xml, xsd

In looking at the stanzaerror.xsd from http://xmpp.org/schemas/ in Visual Studio 2010, I'm getting a warning on the following line...

```
<xs:attribute ref='xml:lang' use='optional'/>
```

Warning:

> Namespace 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace' is not available to be referenced in this schema.

This seems like a very basic XML warning - any ideas?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>    
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
    targetNamespace='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'
    xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'
    elementFormDefault='qualified'>

  <xs:element name='bad-request' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='conflict' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='feature-not-implemented' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='forbidden' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='gone' type='xs:string'/>
  <xs:element name='internal-server-error' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='item-not-found' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='jid-malformed' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='not-acceptable' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='not-allowed' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='not-authorized' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='payment-required' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='policy-violation' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='recipient-unavailable' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='redirect' type='xs:string'/>
  <xs:element name='registration-required' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='remote-server-not-found' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='remote-server-timeout' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='resource-constraint' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='service-unavailable' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='subscription-required' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='undefined-condition' type='empty'/>
  <xs:element name='unexpected-request' type='empty'/>

  <xs:group name='stanzaErrorGroup'>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element ref='bad-request'/>
      <xs:element ref='conflict'/>
      <xs:element ref='feature-not-implemented'/>
      <xs:element ref='forbidden'/>
      <xs:element ref='gone'/>
      <xs:element ref='internal-server-error'/>
      <xs:element ref='item-not-found'/>
      <xs:element ref='jid-malformed'/>
      <xs:element ref='not-acceptable'/>
      <xs:element ref='not-authorized'/>
      <xs:element ref='not-allowed'/>
      <xs:element ref='payment-required'/>
      <xs:element ref='policy-violation'/>
      <xs:element ref='recipient-unavailable'/>
      <xs:element ref='redirect'/>
      <xs:element ref='registration-required'/>
      <xs:element ref='remote-server-not-found'/>
      <xs:element ref='remote-server-timeout'/>
      <xs:element ref='resource-constraint'/>
      <xs:element ref='service-unavailable'/>
      <xs:element ref='subscription-required'/>
      <xs:element ref='undefined-condition'/>
      <xs:element ref='unexpected-request'/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>

  <xs:element name='text'>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base='xs:string'>
          <xs:attribute ref='xml:lang' use='optional'/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>    

  <xs:simpleType name='empty'>
    <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
      <xs:enumeration value=''/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>    
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Warning: if you try to use schemas to validate XMPP, you're going to run into interoperability issues.  That may be what you're looking for (rejecting all "bad" XML), but it is commonly surprising to those who start down this road.  In particular, the "ignore what you do not understand" mantra of XMPP is hard to follow in schema-land, and folks never get the order of elements correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just because you don't need to declare the `xml` namespace for instance documents, doesn't mean the same is true for schemas. I know that seems a bit odd but there it is. You need to define the xml:lang attribute and you need to declare the xml namespace. Generally, I use a simple schema that I import into my schemas. Use the one that the [W3C has made available](http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd).

Import that, declare the namespace. All will be well

```
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
    xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" 
    targetNamespace='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'
    xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'
    elementFormDefault='qualified'>

    <xs:import schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd" namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>

    <xs:element name='bad-request' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='conflict' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='feature-not-implemented' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='forbidden' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='gone' type='xs:string'/>
    <xs:element name='internal-server-error' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='item-not-found' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='jid-malformed' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='not-acceptable' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='not-allowed' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='not-authorized' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='payment-required' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='policy-violation' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='recipient-unavailable' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='redirect' type='xs:string'/>
    <xs:element name='registration-required' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='remote-server-not-found' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='remote-server-timeout' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='resource-constraint' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='service-unavailable' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='subscription-required' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='undefined-condition' type='empty'/>
    <xs:element name='unexpected-request' type='empty'/>

    <xs:group name='stanzaErrorGroup'>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref='bad-request'/>
            <xs:element ref='conflict'/>
            <xs:element ref='feature-not-implemented'/>
            <xs:element ref='forbidden'/>
            <xs:element ref='gone'/>
            <xs:element ref='internal-server-error'/>
            <xs:element ref='item-not-found'/>
            <xs:element ref='jid-malformed'/>
            <xs:element ref='not-acceptable'/>
            <xs:element ref='not-authorized'/>
            <xs:element ref='not-allowed'/>
            <xs:element ref='payment-required'/>
            <xs:element ref='policy-violation'/>
            <xs:element ref='recipient-unavailable'/>
            <xs:element ref='redirect'/>
            <xs:element ref='registration-required'/>
            <xs:element ref='remote-server-not-found'/>
            <xs:element ref='remote-server-timeout'/>
            <xs:element ref='resource-constraint'/>
            <xs:element ref='service-unavailable'/>
            <xs:element ref='subscription-required'/>
            <xs:element ref='undefined-condition'/>
            <xs:element ref='unexpected-request'/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:element name='text'>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base='xs:string'>
                    <xs:attribute ref='xml:lang' use='optional'/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name='empty'>
        <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
            <xs:enumeration value=''/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

I'm not that familiar with XMPP but I suspect that your schema is intended to be imported into another where the XML namespace will have already been declared.

Comment: Yes - it was intended to be imported into another where the XML namespace was declared!  Thanks!

Comment: I would like to add that, in my case, the problem I faced was that I had not declared the **targetNamespace** attribute in the xs:schema element, which we see in the above example as being the _same value_ as the **xmlns** attribute